# Find list in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Would `recursive=-1` help in case of `find("list")` in cakephp. I mean any performance benefit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default

```
$this->Post->find('list');
```

CakePHP make this query:

```
SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`name` FROM `posts` AS `Post` WHERE 1 = 1
```

No recursive query, so changing that command will not improve the query

Answer (score 1):

No, recursive=-1 will not help full in case of $this->Model->find('list').

If you want to find('all') or find('first') , then it will be more use full.

eg. User , VatInfo , VatInfoLog are three models then

1) recursive=-1

$this->VatInfo->find('all')
 Will return only VatInfo table data.

2) recursive=0

$this->VatInfo->find('all')
 Will return $belongsTo User And VatInfo 2 tables data.

3) recursive=1

$this->VatInfo->find('all')
 Will return $belongsTo User ,$hasMany VatInfoLog And VatInfo 3 tables data.

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

In debug mode Cake shows you the running time of each query. Try both ways and see if anything changes. My guess is no, since it's only taking data from one table anyway for `list` queries.

Comment: one more doubt does caching request action caches it everywhere all controller or only specfic location. Hope i am making my self clear

Comment: @Web Unfortunately I don't understand... Maybe you want to make a separate question for it, if it's a separate topic.

Comment: @Web Developer - I agree this should be another question, but have a look at this site. I think you can use request action to cache certain parts of a view, for example a recent articles sidebox. http://mark-story.com/posts/view/how-using-requestaction-increased-performance-on-my-site/